# Why when i look at twitter user view source html i dont see all his tweets in html

Tags: python, html, google-chrome, beautifulsoup, twitter

Why when i look at html source of a twitter page i dont see his tweets in there and how can i get them using BeautifulSoup? For example when i look up html source of
`https://twitter.com/twitter` i dont see there `<img alt="Zdjęcie" draggable="true" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/FJLmN6JVUAIfy3M?format=jpg&amp;name=large" class="css-9pa8cd">` which is one of their tweets and it should be in html source if i can see it in inspect element.

Can someone help me?
Thanks.

Comment: Why not just use twitters api?

Answer (score 1):

Twitter sends only a "partial" HTML response, the actual Twitter website you see in your browser is rendered on your browser most likely through JavaScript. Similarly, the HTML source you see in your devtools via Inspect Element is the *live* HTML, after being rendered through with JavaScript. If you want to get information from Twitter, you should look at using the [Twitter API](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api).